# How to Treat Strings as Bytes in Python 3.7.9?

Tags: python, type-conversion, byte

I have a list of values as below:

```
byte_values = ["\x00", "\x02", ... ]
```

They are meant to be byte values, and I would like to convert them to `ASCII`. However, because there's no `b` in front of them, Python treats them as strings and the decode method doesn't work. Is there a way to get Python to treat these strings as bytes and convert them to actual strings that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str.encode`:

```
>>> byte_values = ["\x00", "\x02", "..." ]
>>> [b.encode() for b in byte_values]
[b'\x00', b'\x02', b'...']
```

For an alternate approach, you can also use the `map` builtin for this:

```py
>>> byte_values = list(map(str.encode, byte_values))
>>> byte_values
[b'\x00', b'\x02', b'...']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves the issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string.

```
byte_values = ["\x00", "\x02", "\x04"]

for string_byte in byte_values:
    print(string_byte.encode())
```